# Not all threads working when trying to swap numbers in array in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to learn using the monitor by creating an array of int, length being 100. It is filled with 0 and I try to make 4 threads that would swap the 0 with numbers from top and bottom of the array.

For some reason only 2 out of 4 threads (and it seems that it is random) executes. I have tried to change it by creating an array and increasing the respected member of the array by 1 for 100k iterations and it seems that every thread did it for about 25k times so I suppose the problem is with the part where I tried to swap 0 in the array.

Here is my code:

```
class addFromBottom implements Runnable{
    int number;
    public addFromBottom(int number){
        this.number=number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = number-1; i <100 ; i+=2) {
            if (MainClass.testMonitor.elementsNotChanged>0)
                MainClass.testMonitor.addNumberFromBottom(number,i);
            else
                break;
        }/*
        while (MainClass.testMonitor.testCounter>0)
            MainClass.testMonitor.testCounter(number);*/
    }
}
class addFromTop implements Runnable{
    int number;
    public addFromTop(int number){
        this.number=number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 95+number; i >=0 ; i-=2) {
            if (MainClass.testMonitor.elementsNotChanged>0){
                MainClass.testMonitor.addNumberFromBottom(number,i);
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }

        /*while (MainClass.testMonitor.testCounter>0)
             MainClass.testMonitor.testCounter(number);*/
    }
}
class monitor
{
    int elementsNotChanged = 100;
    int[] array;
    int testCounter = 100000;
    int[] testArray = new int[]{0,0,0,0};
    public monitor(){
        array=new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            array[i]=0;
        }
    }
    synchronized void addNumberFromBottom(int number,int index){
        if (elementsNotChanged<=0) {
        return;
        }
        if (array[index]==0){
            array[index]=number;
            return;
        }
    }
    //for testing if the threads are working seperatly
    synchronized void testCounter(int number) {
        if (testCounter<=0)
            return;

        testArray[number - 1]++;
        testCounter--;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
class MainClass {
    public static int a=0;
    public static volatile monitor testMonitor;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        testMonitor = new monitor();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new addFromBottom(1));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new addFromBottom(2));
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(new addFromTop(3));
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(new addFromTop(4));
        thread.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();
        thread.join();
        thread2.join();
        thread3.join();
        thread4.join();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("value:   i");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
           System.out.println(testMonitor.array[i]+"        "+i);
        }

        //for testing with the array of 4 elements if all threads are doing their work
       int sum=0;
        for (int i = 0; i <4 ; i++) {
            //System.out.println(testMonitor.testArray[i]);
            sum+=testMonitor.testArray[i];
        }
       // System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: `MainClass.testMonitor.elementsNotChanged>0` There's no memory barrier on that access, your code looks fundamentally broken.

Comment: All your threads are fighting over access to the very same resource. It's not reasonable to expect them to run concurrently.

Comment: I somewhat agree with David that your problem seems poorly chosen to implement multithreading.  I did a quick web search for multithreading problems and found this list, it might be better to choose one of these so the problem you are trying to solve is better bounded: https://linuxtrainers.wordpress.com/2014/12/29/classic-multithreading-problems/